# Can I perform an outer join with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two classes where the key2 of town links to the key 1 of utility. The data is not stored in SQL tables so there's no way I can link and get what I need with SQL.

```
public class Town {
    key1 string { get; set; }
    key2 string { get; set; }
    name string { get; set; }
}

public class Utility {
    key1 string { get; set; }
    key2 string { get; set; }
   name string { get; set; }
}
```

Data looks like the following

```
Town
-------
key1             key2         name
0                 1               Liverpool
0                 2               Preston
0                 3               Wigan

Utility
------

key1      key2
1           West 2
1           West 3
3           East 1
3           East 2
```

What I would like to do is to create a report that showed a list of all the towns with a secondary column to show how many utilities each had.

The report would look something like this

```
Liverpool  2
Preston    0
Wigan      2
```

The data cannot be obtained from just the utility information as I need to show where a town has no utilities. What I was 
thinking of was some code that iterated through the Towns and then for each town did a check and counted up the number
of utility rows.

if the data was stored in the following collections:

```
ICollection<Town> Towns
ICollection<Utility> Utilities
```

Then is there some kind of LINQ query that would somehow join up these collections in a similar way to an outer join in SQL?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you check the LINQ documentation about different operators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work, and it's most straightforward:

```
var results = Towns.Select(t => new { 
                       Town = t,
                       Utilities = Utilities.Count(u => t.key2 == u.key1)
              })
              .ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Microsoft's 101 LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b).  It provides excellent examples of joins.  I don't know how anyone does LINQ without it.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't mark as the correct answer but gave an up vote.

Comment: New url is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/dotnet/try-samples/101-linq-samples/